# How to connect Android to PC

Tags: android, ddms

I'm trying to connect my Samsung Galaxy to PC but ddms tool does not recognize my phone. USB debugging is enabled. What can cause a problem?

PS. I'm using Ubuntu 9.10 OS.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add a rule to /etc/udev/rules.d (i.e.: `51-android.rules`):

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", SYSFS{idVendor}=="04e8", MODE="0666"
```

just in case verify that the id for your phone matches 0x04e8 using `lsusb`.
Once the new rule is added just reload them by

$ sudo udevadm control --reload-rules

Comment: Thanks, it helps. 
In addition, there is  some bug in SDK. The solution is here:
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3293

Answer (score 0):

You have to install the ADB/USB driver corresponding to your Android device.

Comment: I forgot to specify that I have Ubuntu OS on PC.

Answer (score 0):

Summary:

1. [ -s /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules ] || sudo echo 'SUBSYSTEM=="usb", SYSFS{idVendor}=="04e8", MODE="0666"' >/etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules
2. sudo udevadm control --reload-rules
3. Download a patched for Linux ADB executable: http://floe.butterbrot.org/external/adb.gz
4. Replace android-sdk-linux_86/tools/adb with a new one.

Thanks.